# How to make order in executing tests in protractor?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

There is 3 tests, first are for login.
And last test is for the some functionality into app.

But first is executed that 3rd test in audience folder.

**login tests are in separate folder:**

[image]

When audience test is commented then login tests work fine.
When they are included in tests then I get error for all tests.

How to make that login tests folder will be executed first?

login.e2e-spec.ts Login tests:

```
describe('Test login functionality', () => {
  let loginPage: LoginPage;
  let mainDashboardPage: MainDashboardPage;

  const wrongCredentias = {
    username: 'wrongname',
    password: 'wrongpasswd'
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    mainDashboardPage = new MainDashboardPage();
  });

  it('When user try to login with wrong credentials he should stay on “login” page', () => {
    loginPage.navigateTo();
    loginPage.fillCredentials(wrongCredentias);
    expect(loginPage.getNanoLogo().isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('When login is successful — user should be redirected to main-dashboard page', () => {
    loginPage.navigateTo();
    loginPage.fillCredentials();
    expect(mainDashboardPage.getPageTitleText()).toEqual('Main Dashboard');
  });
});
```

audience.e2e-spec.ts  Audience test:

```
describe('Category Rule functionality', () => {
  let loginPage: LoginPage;
  let audiencePage: AudiencePage;


  beforeEach(() => {
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    audiencePage = new AudiencePage();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    Driver.close();
   console.log('afterEach');
  });

  it('Auto QA bot should be able to make new Category rule and save.', () => {

    loginPage.navigateTo();

    loginPage.fillCredentials();

    audiencePage.goToAudienceTab();

    audiencePage.clickAddNewBtn();

    audiencePage.typeTextInAudienceNameField();

    audiencePage.pickRangeLast14Days();

    audiencePage.selectCategoryRule();

    audiencePage.typeTextInCategoryRuleTextArea();

    audiencePage.clickSaveBtn();

    expect(audiencePage.getNotification()).toEqual('Audience saved');
  });
});
```

Comment: The short answer is you shouldn't bother with trying to make them run in an exact order. Fix the tests so they aren't dependent on running in any specific order. They should be independent of other tests.

Comment: Ok thanks, I remove just this two login methods from audience test and work fine.